# ASP.NET XML datasource for Menu

Tags: asp.net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Home>
  <Menu text="Books" url="MenuFromXml.aspx">
   <SubMenu text="Asp.Net" url="MenuFromXml.aspx" id="Asp" ></SubMenu>
   <SubMenu text="Ajax" url="MenuFromXml.aspx" id="AJax"></SubMenu>
  <SubMenu text="MS SQL Server 2005" url="MenuFromXml.aspx" id="SQL"></SubMenu>
<SubMenu text="JavaScript" url="MenuFromXml.aspx" id="Javascript"></SubMenu>
</Menu>
```

The above xml file is the datasource for my menu. I want to return a url like http://www.xyzsite/MenuFromXml.aspx?Id=sql so that I can further use the query string to select required resource for each request. I need you help to solve this problem, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use SiteMap, the SiteMap works like XML.
In SiteMap:

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
   <siteMapNode url="MenuFromXml.aspx" title="Book"  description="">
      <siteMapNode url="MenuFromXml.aspx?id=Asp.Net" title="Asp.Net"  description="" />
      <siteMapNode url="MenuFromXml.aspx?id=AJax" title="Ajax"  description="" />
      <siteMapNode url="MenuFromXml.aspx?id=SQL" title="MS SQL Server 2005"  description="" />
      <siteMapNode url="MenuFromXml.aspx?id=Javascript" title="JavaScript"  description="" />
   </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```